# Converting image into pixel array

Tags: python, numpy, image-recognition

I'm trying to convert a grayscale image's pixels into a numpy array.

Working on google colab.

it shows an error saying: TypeError: 'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable

```
enter code here

    ##load Library
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    from google.colab import files
    from scipy import misc #to see image
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

    from PIL import Image
    pil_im = Image.open('papa.png')
    pil_imgray = pil_im.convert('LA')

    img = np.array(list(pil_imgray.getdata(band=0)), float)
    img.shape = (pil_imgray.size[1], pil_imgray.size[0])
    plt.imshow(img)

    for eachRow in img:
      for eachPixel in eachRow:
          x_test.append(sum(eachPixel)/3.0)
```

Comment: I which line does your error occur?

Comment: Last line when i try to iterate x_test

Answer (score 1):

You can directly load the image using matplotlib:

```
plt.imread('papa.png')
```

or you can convert your PIL image with:

```
img = np.asarray(pil_im)
```

Comment: it shows an error saying: NameError: name 'pil_im' is not defined

Comment: well, pil_im has to be defined. But you had the line `pil_im = Image.open('papa.png')` loading the image and storing it in the variable pil_im.